# c WEXITSTATUS() exited with 255

Tags: c, exec

When a execute this piece os code i receive the info "Exited with value 255". I receive the command by keyboard and i have the information that the string is correct. When i receive the error message the programd dont display (for exmple) the ls -l received by keyboard

```
    printf("Command? ");
    scanf(" %99[^\n]", str);

    p = fork(); 
        if(p > 0 ){   //Dad wait for the child
            wait(&status);
            if(WIFEXITED(status)){
                printf("%d\n",WEXITSTATUS(status));
            }   
        }else{      //Child execute the execlp  
            execlp(str, str,NULL);
            exit(-1);
        }
```

Thanks Guys!
Mark

Comment: `exit -1;` is the cause. BTW: what exactly did you enter into the scanf() line? NOTE: `ls -l` is not a program. `ls` is.

Comment: 1) Yes.. helped now the process has a status = 1 which is good !  2) So... i cant use ls -l in a execlp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`execlp()` expects the arguments to be separated; your string input `ls -l` is not a valid existing executable program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

char *args[] = { "ls", "-l" };
// int main (int argc, char **argv)
int main (void)
{
int p;
int status;

p = fork();
if(p > 0 ){   //Dad wait for the child
     wait(&status);
     if (WIFEXITED(status)){
         printf("%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
        }
     }else{      //Child execute the execlp  
         execlp(args[0], args[0], args[1] ,NULL);
         exit (-1);
     }

exit (0);
}
```

---

Also note that `exit(-1)` (besides being invalid: you should use EXIT_FAILURE) yields an exit result of 0xaaaaaaFF; only the lower few (8) bits are used for the actual exit value; the higher *aaaaaa* bits are used for the cause of the exit, et cetera. -->> see the definition of the `WEXITSTATUS()` and friends in `<sys/wait.h>`.

Comment: Worked Thanks a lot ;) !